# Taking exception.stack prints correctly until attempting to parse the string in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, exception, stack-trace

I am working on a project where I am trying to parse an exception object which I retrieve from the exception object created in a catch, using `exception.stack`.

Below is the code to parse the stacktrace

```
getLineNoFromStacktrace(stack)
    {
        console.log("The stack is");
        console.log(stack);
        const stackSplit = stack.split(/\r?\n/);

        console.log(stackSplit);

        console.log("Stack line 1: ");
        console.log(stack);

        /*stack = stack.replace("http://");
        stack = stack.replace("https://");
        //Get the first colon (:), after this is the line number)*/
        const lineInfo = stack.substring(stack.indexOf(":")+1);

        console.log("Line info: " + lineInfo);
        //Now what we have left, the colon next is the end of the line number

        return lineInfo.substring(0, lineInfo.indexOf(":"));
    }
```

The method above I print the stack which prints out correctly as I am expecting as below:

```
The stack is
index.js:199 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
    at sendHandledException (Home.js:18)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

The next line is I perform a split on the new line characeters \r and \n  and then log out  the array that is created

```
0: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null"
1: "    at sendHandledException (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:642:24)"
2: "    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:8078:18)"
3: "    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:8127:20)"
4: "    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:8187:35)"
5: "    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:8202:29)"
6: "    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:12437:7)"
7: "    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:12469:11)"
8: "    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:12482:9)"
9: "    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:12493:7)"
10: "    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:12704:16"
11: "    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:26389:16)"
12: "    at batchedEventUpdates (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:7876:16)"
13: "    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:12703:7)"
14: "    at attemptToDispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:10186:7)"
15: "    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:10104:23)"
16: "    at unstable_runWithPriority (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:37465:16)"
17: "    at runWithPriority$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:15484:14)"
18: "    at discreteUpdates$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:26406:18)"
19: "    at discreteUpdates (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:7888:16)"
20: "    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:10070:7)"
```

As you can see above, when I log out the stack where I've split by line, the output is completely different so I no longer have the data that I originally had when I first printed the console.

How can I parse this exception.stack and maintain the original the content that first logged at the start of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured what was going on here.

Its to do with ReactJS when built its minimised so the stacktraces become non human readable. When doing a production build in the static/js folder there is main...map file which is the sourcemap that allow you to decode the stacktrace to be human readable and be of any use.

What was happening here, when I print the exception object, the browser has access to the sourcemap (although its not stored on the file system I presume the Node dev server makes it available) so chrome console was able to display the stacktrace as I was expecting, however when I try and get the stack into a variable to parse it, its only the chrome console that has access to the sourcemap, not the code itself so I end up parsing the encoded stacktrace.